# How to import table from BigQuery to Cloud SQL

Tags: google-bigquery, google-cloud-sql

I want to import log table from BigQuery to Cloud SQL.

- source(In BigQuery): `logs_20161013` table.
- destination(In Cloud SQL): `logs` table.

I'm creating `logs_YYYYMMDD` table everyday.
I want to insert log data to Cloud SQL(logs table) on batch program.

```
logs_20161013(BigQuery) -> logs(Cloud SQL)
logs_20161014(BigQuery) -> logs(Cloud SQL)
logs_20161015(BigQuery) -> logs(Cloud SQL)
...
```

I want to do that on Command-Line.

What is the easiest way?

I already tried to below:

- Exported CSV file from BigQuery to local and Cloud Storage.
- `mysqlimport --fields-terminated-by=',' -hxxx.xxx.xxx.xxx -uroot -ppassword database-name /tmp/logs.csv` <- (didn't work)
- `LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/logs.csv' INTO TABLE logs FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES;` <- (didn't work)
- `LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE '/tmp/logs.csv' INTO TABLE logs FIELDS TERMINATED BY ',' IGNORE 1 LINES;` <- (didn't work)
- Import from GUI(Cloud Console) <- (It's works, but it's works only GUI)

Comment: Can you paste what errors you had when you tried using LOAD DATA INFILE or mysqlimport?

Comment: mysql> LOAD DATA INFILE '/tmp/logs_20160101.csv' INTO TABLE logs;
ERROR 1045 (28000): Access denied for user 'root'@'%' (using password: YES)